# Any IDE or plugins to visual formatting such as bg color or add tags to selected blocks of code?

Tags: ide, productivity, code-beautification

I am having lots of code to reorganize. To bring all scattered code to a single place and organize them. It will be easy if I can able to add some tags to code or change something visually such as background colour to the selected blocks of code. So I don't need to go through the code again and again.

Currently using IntelliJ IDEA. They suggested TODO comments and bookmarks but both opens in a different popup window. I don't want to switch between my file and window all the time.

Just now I came to know about chrome dev tools code coverage indication. They highlight near line number area. Something like that will be much better. 
[image]

Comment: I prefer to use an IDE with good navigational capabilities, like a list of all functions/classes/variables, and just jump to that (good question, though)

Comment: What IDE or editor?